# BrowserStack + Protractor + TravisCi and secure localhost server - configuration

Tags: protractor, travis-ci, browserstack

Trying to have an e2e test to test my server and it's UI on TraviCI. I'm however not able to come up with the necessary configuration in order to run all the components and access seleniumServer on BrowserStack. 
I am able to get my session started, but when launching a browser to `https://localhost:3000/login`  I see that the browser shows a page not found. If I manually run the ./BrowserStackLocal tool and use browserstack to access my localhost, I can do so no problem. 
Here are my files:

### ./travis.yaml

....

```
addons:
  browserstack:
    username: "<my username>"
    access_key:
      secure: "<secure key goes here>"
```

### config.js

```
var browserstack = require('browserstack-local');

exports.config = {

allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

specs: [
    'specs/*.js'
],

'seleniumAddress': 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

'capabilities': {
    'browserstack.user': '<my username>', //<<--- I also had a version without these properties for browserstack, and that didn't work either
    'browserstack.key': '<my key>',
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'acceptSslCerts': true,
    'browserstack.debug': true,
    'chromeOptions': {
        'excludeSwitches': ["disable-popup-blocking"]
    }
},


baseUrl: 'https://localhost:3000/',
rootElement: 'div[ng-app]',

framework: 'jasmine',

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
},

// Code to start browserstack local before start of test
beforeLaunch: function(){
    console.log("Connecting local");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        exports.bs_local = new browserstack.Local();
        exports.bs_local.start({'key': exports.config.capabilities['browserstack.key'] }, function(error) {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            console.log('Connected. Now testing...');

            resolve();
        });
    });
},

// Code to stop browserstack local after end of test
afterLaunch: function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        exports.bs_local.stop(resolve);
    });
}

};
```

Comment: Are you able to share a build log?

Comment: The build log just shows the elements on page weren't found. When I look at the BrowserStack video, I can see that https://localhost:3000/login page opened in browser, but not found. Tells me the local testing tunnel isn't running on Travis so browserstack has no access it it.

Comment: If I have the Travis addon configured, and run the tests with above config I see an error which indicates local tunnel already running (the addon starts the tunnel). So it certainly tries to start it , but no other errors that are available show where the issue could be and what is misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing your local/private environment on BrowserStack Automate you have to follow these steps:

1) Create the Local Testing connection via the [BrowserStackLocal](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#command-line) Binary.

2) Add the capability `'browserstack.local' : true` in your config file.

I do not see the capability in the config.js file. Add the capability and things should work.

Your script looks similar to the one [here](https://github.com/browserstack/protractor-browserstack/blob/master/conf/local.conf.js).

Comment: I added the browserstack.local setting, but still getting the same issue.

Comment: One question though about (1) ... You're saying to create a local connection using the binary. Locally i have downloaded and run the binary, but if I have that binary running while I run the tests I get an error indication port is already taken. When I kill the binary my protractor spec runs fine against Browserstack. So is this binary needed to run an stop to configure something on the environment before local testing can be done ? It certainly can't be running while tests are running.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem myself recently. First, Ashwin is right that you need to add `'browserstack.local' : true` to your protractor config file. Next you need to add `"browserstack-local": "^1.3.0"` to `package.json` under `devDependencies`. This is required for the Browserstack Local binary to be installed on your build server.

**package.json:**

```
...
"devDependencies": {
 "browserstack-local": "^1.3.0"
}
```

Beyond that, it is not a problem with the config/setup. Rather, it is *how* you kick off the tests that affects the port your app is served on.

The reason it works when you run with the local binary is because your app is started on http://localhost:3000.

But when you build and run the app via Travis (by running `ng e2e` or similar), it actually starts your app on a different port (refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571482/how-to-specify-the-port-and-host-for-ng-e2e-using-configuration) for more on the angular ports). You can confirm this by looking at the console log, it should start with something like this:

```
> ng e2e

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49152, open your browser on http://localhost:49152 **
```

In the example above, it started on port 49152. So now if you have localhost:3000 hardcoded somewhere in your test spec, it won't find anything there. To fix this, in your test spec file, instead of `browser.get('http://localhost:3000/login')`, try  `browser.get(browser.baseUrl + '/login')`.

I realize this answer is probably too late for you, but hopefully it will be helpful to others.

Comment: I just remembered that we need to add the browserstack local binary as a devDependency. Edited my answer.