# How to specify the port and host for ng e2e using configuration

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

How do you set the port and host for the `ng e2e` command using a configuration file?

I am aware that it is possible to use the following statement at the command line

```
ng e2e --port <port number> --host <host>
```

This works nicely, but it would be more convenient to set the port and address in the configuration file. I have looked inside `.angular-cli.json` and found that there is a file called `protractor.config.js`, I've not been able to figure out what settings to use in that file, there's a `baseUrl` setting, but changing that does not make any difference to the port that is used by the `ng e2e` command. It seems to be using a random port.

Aside from `baseUrl` I have also tried setting `port` and `seleniumPort` but they make no difference.

After entering the `ng e2e` command the following output appears in the in the console

```
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:49155 **
```

In the `protractor.config.js` I have `baseUrl` set as `http://localhost:50000`. I have observed the tests executing and I can see that the browser is using the address `http://localhost:49155` which is not the address that I desire.

`ng --version` returns the followin

> @angular/cli: 1.0.0
>   node: 7.7.1
>   os: win32 x64
>   @angular/common: 4.0.3
>   @angular/compiler: 4.0.3
>   @angular/core: 4.0.3
>   @angular/forms: 4.0.3
>   @angular/http: 4.0.3
>   @angular/platform-browser: 4.0.3
>   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.3
>   @angular/router: 4.0.3
>   @angular/cli: 1.0.0
>   @angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.3

Comment: What do you mean *"used by the `ng e2e` command"*? Are you talking about the port that selenium is running on, or the port it will look for the app running on? The latter you can definitely change using `baseUrl`. Could you show the output you're getting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am talking about the port that the app is running on. The first line of output is `** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:49155 **` but I have set `baseUrl` as `http://localhost:50000`

Comment: That's the port that `ng serve` is running on, surely, not necessarily what `ng e2e` is looking for?

Comment: I've tried entering nonexistant host and port as baseUrl and the tests pass, so it seems that baseUrl does not do anything, since I can enter the same nonexistant host and port using the command line arguments and an error will occur

Answer (score 13):

Set the host and port in `angular.json` by modifying the project `webapp-e2e` , e.g:

```
"e2e": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
  "options": {
    "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
    "devServerTarget": "webapp:serve",
    "port": 4201
  }
```

This will override the port being used once webapp:serve-command is invoked by angular-cli. Forget the protractor.conf.js file - it's not used until later in the process.

Thus you can run `ng serve --watch` (for serving and unit tests) and `ng e2e` (for e2e tests) independently or in parallell.

br,
Jens

Comment: When I add the `port` property, I get the following error message when running `ng e2e`: `Data path "['e2e']" should NOT have additional properties(port).`

Comment: Same as @NathanFriend

Comment: Same here as well.

Answer (score 11):

I have not seen a config for the port the dev server runs on when running `ng e2e`

your best bet is probably an NPM script: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

1. Add `"e2e":"ng e2e --port <port number> --host <host>"` to `package.json` under `scripts`
2. Use the script by running `npm run e2e`, this will run the script `e2e` in `package.json`, in this case your `ng e2e --port <port number> --host <host>`

It isnt a config file, but it works just like one.

Answer (score 5):

baseUrl property somehow does not work in protractor.config.js, but you can programatically set the property in onPrepare method in the same config.js

```
{
    onPrepare() {
        browser.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/';
    },
}
```

I have been using this solution in Angular 1.x, still works for Angular 2/4

Comment: I've noticed this as well; when using Angular CLI `ng e2e` command, the baseUrl is overwritten for some reason.

Comment: I could not find the `protractor.config.js` file anywhere because it was renamed `protractor.conf.js` in the latest versions, apparently.

Answer (score 5):

I have found out that when we call the command `ng e2e`, the development server will be running by default on http://localhost:49152/

To be able to specify the port and host for ng e2e using configuration we will use the property `baseUrl`on the `protractor.conf.js` file. We will need to:

- serve the app separatly
- then we set serve to **false** when calling `ng e2e`, so **Protratcor** will communication with `baseUrl` directly

For example:

- we need first, on the **protractor.conf.js** to put:
  `baseUrl:'http://localhost:8088'`
- run the command :
  `ng serve --port 8088`
- on another shell run the test:
  `ng e2e --serve false`

There is also another maneuver where we don't use `baseUrl`. we only need to:
 - in shell 1 run: `ng serve --port 4200`
 - in shell 2 run: `ng e2e --serve false --base-href=http://localhost:4200`